# Як правильно вживати "признався" чи "зізнався"?

Tags: вживання-слів

"Ти признайся мені...", - так звучать слова відомої пісні Назарія Яремчука. Чи правильно вживати  це слово у всіх випадках, окрім значення "[Освідчуватися, освідчитися і признаватися, признатися, зізнаватися, зізнатися в коханні"](http://onlinecorrector.com.ua/%d0%be%d1%81%d0%b2%d1%96%d0%b4%d1%87%d1%83%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%be%d1%81%d0%b2%d1%96%d0%b4%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%8f/). Оскільки, у [Академічному тлумачному  словнику(1970—1980)](http://sum.in.ua/s/pryznavatysja) знаходимо, що  вживання  словосполучення "признаватися в коханні" є правильним (на даний час ця інформація неактуальна), то  чи можна вживати це слово у всіх інших випадках? Чи замінювати його на "зізнаватися"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Щодо того, що правильно використовувати конструкцію "признаватися в коханні", то на сайті [Оnlinecorrector](http://onlinecorrector.com.ua/%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%B4%D1%87%D1%83%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%B4%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8F/) пише так:

> Замініть нехарактерний для української мови вислів *признаватися*, признатися, зізнаватися, зізнатися *в коханні* на стилістично кращий варіант: **освідчуватися, освідчитися**.

У сучасному [СУМ-8](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=36247&page=1144) наведено таке визначення щодо поняття "зізнаватися":

> **ЗІЗНАВА́ТИСЯ**, наю́ся, нає́шся, недок., ЗІЗНА́ТИСЯ, а́юся, а́єшся, док. 1. ***Говорити відверто*** про свій стан, свої вчинки і т. ін.; признаватися в чому-небудь.
>
> Марія зізналася, що тоді, коли Іванові оголосили сувору догану, вона хотіла була прийти до нього, але не зважилась (М. Руденко).

Щодо заміни понять "зізнавати", "признаватися" одне одним, аби уникнути помилки, не варто, адже ці слова є синонімами (окрім значення "освідчуватись"). На підтвердження подаю інформацію з [Офіційного сайту Української мови](https://ukrainskamova.com/publ/slovnik_sinonimiv/p/priznavatisja/38-1-0-13201):

> Синоніми до слова **ПРИЗНАВАТИСЯ**: (в чому) **зізнаватися**, ***казати правду про, визнавати що***; (до чого) не цуратися; (у коханні) освідчуватися; (до кого) обзиватися, не цуратися; (до слів) не зрікатися чого, визнавати що; (з ч. не) не впізнавати, не хотіти знати.

Отже, якщо слова "зізнаватися", "признаватися" будуть у значенні "говорити правду, говорити відверто, вазнавати щось", то вони виступатимуть синонімами. Таким чином замінювати "признаватися" на "зізнаватися" нема потреби.